# InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

```
  timers: Observable<ITimer>[]=[];
```

Template is:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of timers | async">
  {{ item.time }}
  <div (click)="remove(item.index)">Remove</div>
</div>
```

Why I get this error?

If not initialize `this.timers` then async works. Elsewise I can not get lenght in this  method:

```
 add() {
    let options = {
      finishDate: null,
      time: null,
      index: this.timers.length
    };

    this.timers.push(this.create(options));

  }
```

In line: `index: this.timers.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular Docs on the [**`async`**](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe:

> The `async` pipe subscribes to an `Observable` or `Promise` and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the `async` pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the `async` pipe `unsubscribe`s automatically to avoid potential memory leaks.

But from your property declaration, it seems that it's an `Array`. So it won't work.

Don't initialize the `timers` property here and change the type of `timers` to `Observable<ITimer[]>`

Something like this:

```
timers: Observable<ITimer[]>;
```

It would now depend on how you initialize the `timers` property. However you do, just make sure that it is an `Observable`

### UPDATE:

Based on your use case, you can make this as an Array of `Observable`s. Which is something that you already have.

```
timers: Observable<ITimer>[]=[];
```

You are just using the `async` pipe at a wrong place. Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item$ of timers">
  <div *ngIf="(item$ | async) as item">
    {{ item.time }}
    <div (click)="remove(item.index)">Remove</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpzunb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

#### Alternatively

You can also create a BehaviorSubject>:

```
timersArray: ITimer[] = [];
timers$: BehaviorSubject<Array<ITimer>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<ITimer>>(this.timersArray);
```

And then when you add, you can update the `timersArray` first and then update the `BehaviorSubject` stream by calling the `next` method on `timers$`:

```
add() {
  let options = {
    finishDate: null,
    time: new Date(),
    index: this.timers.length
  };
  this.timers.push(this.create(options));
  this.timersArray.push(options);
  this.timers$.next(this.timersArray);
}
```

And then you could use this in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (timers$ | async)">
  {{ item.time }}
  <button (click)="remove(item.index)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

---

> Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-javsk3?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Then of not initialize I can not do this: `this.timers.length` it gives an error

Comment: Can you please update your question with the relevant code and more information on what exactly are you trying to do here? That would help me understand the use case and then I can probably suggest some solution :)

Comment: Done, see question